# Broken PHP files of my extension after installation

Tags: magento-connect

I created my extension for Magento 1.9.

It works on my localhost.

Packed it using Magento Package Extensions.

Uploaded it to Magento Connect.

Created new empty shop with Magento 1.9.

Install module.

And get these errors:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /Users/noff/Sites/magento2.dm/app/code/community/Rees46/Personalization/Helper/Data.php on line 63
```

When I open file Data.php using Sublime Editor on new Magento installation, I see this string at the end of file:

[image]

So, question is: what is it and how it happens in my file? Original file hasn't this symbols before installation of extension. When I untar file tarred by Extension Package tool - file is OK.

Comment: in which encoding did you save the file? does it maybe differ from the encoding on your new server?

Comment: Seems like an issue with your tar/untar process.